# java variable definition pattern

Tags: java, identifier

I defined an array as follows:

```
int[][] temp_blocks = new int[dim][dim];
```

But I got a warning:

```
Name 'temp_blocks' must match pattern `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$|^[A-Z][A-Z_0-9]*$`.
```

Any idea why it is that, and how to fix it?

Comment: It seems like your compiler doesn't like the underscore.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If that's the case, then the compiler is in error. [Java allows underscores in variable names](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html).

Comment: Accoring to the regular expression, it only allows underscores in an ALL_CAPS variable (which can also contain digits).

Comment: And of course the common Java language style would have the name as `tempBlocks`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is telling you that names of variables must match the regular expression `^[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*$|^[A-Z][A-Z_0-9]*$`. This regular expression states that there are two types of variables names:

1. Variables starting with a lowercase letter. These can contain lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and digits.
2. Variables starting with an uppercase letter. These can contain uppercase letters, digits, and underscores.

Your variable name `temp_blocks` doesn't fit these conditions since it starts with a lowercase letter but contains an underscore.

Comment: Nice Explanation,
Just googled around the variable name conventions,
 
Variable names begin with a lowercase letter. The initial letter of any subsequent words in the name are capitalized, and underscores are not used to separate words (or scope variables).

http://www.iwombat.com/standards/JavaStyleGuide.html#Attribute%20and%20Local%20Variable%20Names